# CUDA spinlock implementation with Independent Thread Scheduling supported?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I'd like to revisit the situation of implementing a simple spinlock on CUDA, now that [Independent Thread Scheduling](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/inside-volta/) (ITS) has been introduced for a while.

My code looks like this:

```cpp
// nvcc main.cu -arch=sm_75
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "cuda.h"

constexpr int kN = 21;

using Ptr = uint8_t*;

struct DynamicNode {
  int32_t lock = 0;
  int32_t n = 0;
  Ptr ptr = nullptr;
};

__global__ void func0(DynamicNode* base) {
  for (int i = 0; i < kN; ++i) {
    DynamicNode* dn = base + i;
    atomicAdd(&(dn->n), 1);
    // entering the critical section
    auto* lock = &(dn->lock);
    while (atomicExch(lock, 1) == 1) {
    }
    __threadfence();
    // Use a condition to artificially boost the complexity
    // of loop unrolling for the compiler
    if (dn->ptr == nullptr) {
      dn->ptr = reinterpret_cast<Ptr>(0xf0);
    }
    // leaving the critical section
    atomicExch(lock, 0);
    __threadfence();
  }
}

int main() {
  DynamicNode* dev_root = nullptr;
  constexpr int kRootSize = sizeof(DynamicNode) * kN;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_root, kRootSize);
  cudaMemset(dev_root, 0, kRootSize);
  func0<<<1, kN>>>(dev_root);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  std::vector<int32_t> host_root(kRootSize / sizeof(int32_t), 0);
  cudaMemcpy(host_root.data(), dev_root, kRootSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaFree((void*)dev_root);
  const auto* base = reinterpret_cast<const DynamicNode*>(host_root.data());
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < kN; ++i) {
    auto& dn = base[i];
    std::cout << "i=" << i << " len=" << dn.n << std::endl;
    sum += dn.n;
  }
  std::cout << "sum=" << sum << " expected=" << kN * kN << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, there's a naive spinlock implemented in `func0`. While I understand that this would result in deadlock on older archs (e.g. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/atomic-locks/25522/2), if I compile the code with `nvcc main.cu -arch=sm_75`, it actually runs without blocking indefinitely.

However, what I do notice is that `n` in each `DynamicNode` went completely garbage. Here's the output on `GeForce RTX 2060 (laptop)`, which I can reproduce deterministically:

```
i=0 len=21
i=1 len=230
i=2 len=19
i=3 len=18
i=4 len=17
i=5 len=16
i=6 len=15
i=7 len=14
i=8 len=13
i=9 len=12
i=10 len=11
i=11 len=10
i=12 len=9
i=13 len=8
i=14 len=7
i=15 len=6
i=16 len=5
i=17 len=4
i=18 len=3
i=19 len=2
i=20 len=1
sum=441 expected=441
```

Ideally, the length of all the `DynamicNode`s should be `kN`. I've also tried with larger `kN` (*), and it's always that only `sum` is correct.

Have I misunderstood something about ITS? Can ITS actually warrant such a lock implementation? If not, what am I missing here?

(*) With a smaller `kN`, `nvcc` might actually unroll the loop, from what I saw in the PTX. I've never observed any problem when the loop is unrolled.

---

Update 02/02/2021

I should have clarified that I tested this on `CUDA 11.1`. According to @robert-crovella, upgrading to `11.2` would fix the problem.

---

Update 02/03/2021

I tested with `CUDA 11.2` driver, it still didn't fully solve the problem with a larger `kN`:

| kN \ CUDA | 11.1 | 11.2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | N | OK |
| 128 | N | N |

Comment: I was able to reproduce the observation, approximately, on CUDA 11.1 or before.  When I update to CUDA 11.2, the problem goes away.  Please update your machine to CUDA 11.2 and retest.  Note that this may necessitate loading a new GPU driver also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah I was indeed using CUDA 11.1

Comment: I'm seeing somewhat different, but also buggy, numbers with an RTX6000 and CUDA 10.2.89.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been some sort of code generation defect in the compiler.  The solution seems to be to update to CUDA 11.2 (or newer, presumably, in the future).

Comment: Hi, I've updated my post. CUDA 11.2 only worked when `kN = 21`, but not for a larger `kN = 128`.

Comment: You may wish to [file a bug](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911) at developer.nvidia.com.